# Force python subprocesses to run in specific order

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I have a program in which I need two processes to run simultaneously and one process needs to start before the other one. There are other subprocesses involved based on things like how far along in the script I am and what errors occur during some processes but none of those need to run while the main two are running.

```
sys.stdout.flush()

proc1 = subprocess.Popen(<command line tool>, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) 
proc1_data, proc1_stderr = proc1.communicate() 
time.sleep(0.1) # allow time proc1 to kick in

proc2 = subprocess.Popen(<command line tool>, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2_data, proc2_stderr = proc2.communicate() 

proc2.wait()
proc1.kill()
proc2.kill()

# do error checking among other things in other subprocesses based on this data
```

This works some of the time, but from looking at LEDs on hardware that turn on during proc1 and proc2, I can see that they are sometimes out of sync, as in proc2 will sometimes run and finish before proc1 turns on.

Is there any way to ensure that the processes start in order? And that proc2 runs before proc1 finishes?

Answer (score 1):

Once they're started, subprocesses are independent entities which will run at whatever speed they feel like. You can't control what happens inside each subprocesses - *unless* you use some form of inter-process communication (IPC) between them.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do here, but if it's the case that you don't want subprocess 2 to pass a specific checkpoint until subprocess 1 has passed its own checkpoint, IPC is exactly what you need here. If you're on a Unix-ish system (including macOS), you could use a [semaphore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html): have subprocess 2 call `sem_wait` to block until subprocess 1 calls `sem_post`. Windows has a very similar concept.

Comment: My only requirement is that process 2 only runs while process 1 is running, or at the very least starts after process 1 starts. Process 1 sends data over USB to a hardware device for x seconds, process 2 reads data over usb from another hardware device that relies on the state of the first hardware device.